# How to locate the position of a periodic orbit

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, periodic-function

These are the equations of the dynamical system

```
Vn = (-G*Mn)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + cn^2];
Vd = (-G*Md)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + (s + h)^2];
Vh = (-G*Mh)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + ch^2];
Vb = (G*Mb)/(2*a)*(ArcSinh[(x[t] - a)*(y[t]^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)] - 
 ArcSinh[(x[t] + a)*(y[t]^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)]); 
pot = Vn + Vd + Vh + Vb;
H = 1/2*(ux[t]^2 + uy[t]^2) + pot - om*(x[t]*uy[t] - y[t]*ux[t]);
```

and these are the values of the parameters

```
G = 1; Mn = 400; cn = 0.25;
Md = 7000; s = 3; h = 0.175;
Mb = 3500; a = 10; c = 1;
Mh = 20000; ch = 20;
om = 4.5;
H0 = -3180;
```

The initial conditions of the orbit are

```
x00 = 10.77; y0 = 0; ux0 = 0;
Ht = H /. {x[t] -> x00, y[t] -> y0, ux[t] -> ux0};
pot0 = pot /. {x[t] -> x00, y[t] -> y0};
py0 = x00*om - Sqrt[x00^2*om^2 + 2*(H0 - pot0)];
sol = Solve[Ht == H0];
uy0 = uy[t] /. sol[[1]] 
tmin = 0; tmax = 1;
```

The set of the equations of motion

```
DifferentialEquations[H_, om_, x00_, y0_, ux0_, uy0_] := 
 Module[{Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4},
 Deq1 = x'[t] == ux[t] + om*y[t];
 Deq2 = y'[t] == uy[t] - om*x[t]; 
 Deq3 = ux'[t] == -D[pot, x[t]] + om*uy[t];
 Deq4 = uy'[t] == -D[pot, y[t]] - om*ux[t];

{Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4, x[0] == x00, y[0] == y0, ux[0] == ux0, 
 uy[0] == uy0}
]
```

and the numerical integration

```
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, x00, y0, ux0, uy0];
sol = NDSolve[DE, {x[t], y[t], ux[t], uy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12];
xx[t_] = x[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy[t_] = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
uxx[t_] = ux[t] /. sol[[1]];
uyy[t_] = uy[t] /. sol[[1]];
```

For `x00 = 10.77` the corresponding orbit is the follwoing

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{xx[t], yy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, Axes -> False, 
       Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black, 
       AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We see that the orbit is not periodic. However if we use `x00 = 10.77403` we get

[image]

which is indeed a periodic orbit.

My question is obviously the following: how can I locate the exact (let's say with 10 decimal digits) position of the periodic orbit? Somehow inside the `NDSolve` there should be an iterative process changing the value of `x00` until it hits the periodic point.

The corresponding FORTRAN code indicates that the position of the periodic orbit is at `x00 = 10.774029735833850`. So any provided method here must give the same result.

**NOTE:** The energy level `H0 = -3180` should be remain the same while searching for the `x00` value of the periodic orbit. `x00` is always in the interval [9,12], so the initial guess 10.77 should be corrected somehow so as to hit the exact the periodic point. Also for `x = x00` it should be `y0 = ux0 = 0`.

**EDIT**

DO loop for variable value of the energy

```
data = {};
Do[
 x00 = 10.5; y0 = 0; ux0 = 0;
 tmin = 0; tmax = 1;
 Ht = H /. {x[t] -> x00, y[t] -> y0, ux[t] -> ux0};
 pot0 = pot /. {x[t] -> x00, y[t] -> y0};
 py0 = x00*om - Sqrt[x00^2*om^2 + 2*(H0 - pot0)];
 sol = Solve[Ht == H0];
 uy0 = uy[t] /. sol[[1]];
 Clear[uy0];
 fuy0[x0_] := 
 Solve[(H /. {x[t] -> x0, y[t] -> y0, ux[t] -> ux0, uy[t] -> uy0}) ==
    H0, uy0][[1, 1, 2]]
 f[xp_, tp_] := 
  Module[{xx = x[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, yy = y[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp,
   uxx = ux[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, 
   uyy = uy[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. 
    solp}, {Norm[{xx[tp], yy[tp], uxx[tp], uyy[tp]} - {xx[0], 
     yy[0], uxx[0], uyy[0]}], Norm[xx[tp] - xx[0]]}]
 DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, x0, y0, ux0, uy0];
solp = ParametricNDSolve[
DE, {x, y, ux, uy}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x0, uy0}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
AccuracyGoal -> 12];
pos = Quiet@
FindRoot[f[xp, tp], {{xp, x00}, {tp, .5}}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
AccuracyGoal -> 12];
xper = xp /. pos[[1]];
tper = tp /. pos[[2]];
AppendTo[data, {xper, tper}],    
{H0, -3180, -3170, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: The answer to [The Orbit and Perigee of the Flamsteed comet](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25231/the-orbit-and-perigee-of-the-flamsteed-comet) should be helpful.

Comment: Are all of `{x0, y0, ux0, uy0}` free parms?

Comment: @belisarius x0 is to be determined, y0 = 0, ux0 = 0, uy0 ---> obtained from the energy integral. BTW nice to hear from you again!

Comment: One thing to point out, numerical solvers often exhibit [energy drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_drift) where the system appears to lose or gain energy as the simulation progresses. So, any fixed point you find needs to be considered suspicious until you've demonstrated that the simulation does not exhibit drift.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, any numerical integrator has an error but in this case the error is beyond the twelfth significant figure.

Comment: At that level, I'd treat the 9th and 10th digits with suspicion, possibly the 8th, depending on how long it runs. But, it should be good enough.

Comment: @rcollyer See that when `x00 = 10.77403` (only five decimal digits) the orbit is periodic.

Comment: My experience is with a double well oscillator, and along the separatrix, it was very clear which methods drifted in energy. So, I was just leaving the note as a caution. But, if you've done the checks, then ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `uy0` defined in terms of `x0` as

```
Clear[uy0];
fuy0[x0_] := 
 Solve[(H /. {x[t] -> x0, y[t] -> y0, ux[t] -> ux0, uy[t] -> uy0}) == H0, uy0][[1, 1, 2]]
```

the criterion for a repeated orbit as

```
f[xp_, tp_] := 
 Module[{xx = x[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, yy = y[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, 
   uxx = ux[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, uyy = uy[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp}, 
   {Norm[{xx[tp], yy[tp], uxx[tp], uyy[tp]} - {xx[0], yy[0], uxx[0], uyy[0]}], 
    Norm[xx[tp] - xx[0]]}]
```

and other quantities as in the question, then

```
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, x0, y0, ux0, uy0];
solp = ParametricNDSolve[DE, {x, y, ux, uy}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x0, uy0}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12]

NumberForm[Quiet@
   FindRoot[f[xp, tp], {{xp, x00}, {tp, .5}}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12],
 15]   
(* {xp -> 10.774029731533837, tp -> 0.5320581303031949} *)
```

where the first number is the `x0` initial condition, and the second number the period.  The calculation is virtually instantaneous.

**Addendum: Plot of Closed Curve**

```
Clear[xx, yy, uxx, uyy];
xx = x[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. ans[[1]] /. solp;
yy = y[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. ans[[1]] /. solp;
uxx = ux[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. ans[[1]] /. solp;
uyy = uy[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. ans[[1]] /. solp;
plot = ParametricPlot[{xx[t], yy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Response to Edit with new code**

```
Vn = (-G*Mn)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + cn^2];
Vd = (-G*Md)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + (s + h)^2];
Vh = (-G*Mh)/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + ch^2];
Vb = (G*Mb)/(2*a)*(ArcSinh[(x[t] - a)*(y[t]^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)] - 
      ArcSinh[(x[t] + a)*(y[t]^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)]); 
pot = Vn + Vd + Vh + Vb;
H = 1/2*(ux[t]^2 + uy[t]^2) + pot - om*(x[t]*uy[t] - y[t]*ux[t]);
G = 1; Mn = 400; cn = 0.25; Md = 7000; s = 3; h = 0.175; Mb = 3500; a = 10;     
c = 1; Mh = 20000; ch = 20; om = 4.5;
x00 = 10.77; y0 = 0; ux0 = 0; tmin = 0; tmax = 1;
DifferentialEquations[H_, om_, x00_, y0_, ux0_, uy0_] := 
  Module[{Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4},
  Deq1 = x'[t] == ux[t] + om*y[t];
  Deq2 = y'[t] == uy[t] - om*x[t]; 
  Deq3 = ux'[t] == -D[pot, x[t]] + om*uy[t];
  Deq4 = uy'[t] == -D[pot, y[t]] - om*ux[t];  
  {Deq1, Deq2, Deq3, Deq4, x[0] == x00, y[0] == y0, ux[0] == ux0, uy[0] == uy0}];
data = {};
Do[Clear[uy0];
fuy0[x0_] := Solve[(H /. {x[t] -> x0, y[t] -> y0, ux[t] -> ux0, uy[t] -> uy0}) ==
H0, uy0][[1, 1, 2]];
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, x0, y0, ux0, uy0];
solp = ParametricNDSolve[DE, {x, y, ux, uy}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x0, uy0}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12];
f[xp_, tp_] := Module[{xx = x[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, yy = y[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, 
uxx = ux[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp, uyy = uy[xp, fuy0[xp]] /. solp}, 
{Norm[{xx[tp], yy[tp], uxx[tp], uyy[tp]} - {xx[0], yy[0], uxx[0], uyy[0]}], 
Norm[xx[tp] - xx[0]]}];
ans = NumberForm[Quiet@FindRoot[f[xp, tp], {{xp, x00}, {tp, .5}}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12], 15];
xper = xp /. ans[[1, 1]];
tper = tp /. ans[[1, 2]];
AppendTo[data, {xper, tper}], {H0, -3180, -3170, 1}]

data
(* {{10.774, 0.532058}, {10.7705, 0.53089}, {10.7668, 0.529734}, {10.7631, 0.52859}, 
    {10.7594, 0.527458}, {10.7556, 0.52634}, {10.7517, 0.525235}, {10.7478, 0.524144}, 
    {10.7439, 0.523068}, {10.7399, 0.522006}, {10.7358, 0.52096}} *)
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I owe you a six-pack!

Comment: Just a comment. If I want to directly plot the periodic orbit after calculating the position what should I do?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z   I have added the plot and associated code, as you requested.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. I created a loop for finding the position of the orbits for variable value of the energy. However it does not work.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  I do not have the time now to debug your added code, but I did notice that `om` is undefined.  I also ran the single case `H = -3170`, obtaining `{xp -> 10.735836096248457, tp -> 0.5209596411249624}`

Comment: For single values of energy it works fine. All I did was to fit your code into a DO loop. It won't take you too much to inspect. I wouldn't ask if it was not important. many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  You have many, many undefined quantities in your new code.

Comment: If I remove the DO loop it works fine for a single value of `H0`. Disregard my EDIT and please try to explain how to envelop your solution in a DO loop with variable `H0` let's say in the interval [-3180,-3000].

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  Done

Comment: Your update seems to work. However the loop is much more slower. Also for some values of `H0` the results are not correct.

Comment: For what values of H0 are the answers not correct, and what should the answers be?

Comment: Try for example `H0 = -2730`. `x0 = 13.0829`, while the period is `-4.39383*10^-9` which is obviously not correct.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  Remember that `FindRoot` requires reasonable guesses.  For H0 = -2730, choosing `x00 = 2.4` yields `{xp -> 2.4343843379119816, tp -> 0.3677217902335441}`.  Eventually, you will have to change `0.5` in `FindRoot` too.  Also, remember that there may be more than one solution for a given `H0`.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit

Here is a solution that addresses energy level:

```
(* parameter dep. system *)
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, X, Y, UX, UY] ;
(* function of initial coordinates for fixed end time *)
f1[val_?NumberQ] := With[
 {T=val},
 ParametricNDSolveValue[
    DE,
    {x[T],y[T],ux[T],uy[T]},
    {t, 0, T}, 
    {X,Y,UX,UY},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 20, "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}},
    WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision
]] ;
(* find fixed point for fixed end time *) 
f2[val_?NumberQ] := With[
    {fun = f1[val]},
    {X,Y,UX,UY} /. FindRoot[fun[X,Y,UX,UY]=={X,Y,UX,UY},{X,x00},{Y,y0},{UX,ux0},{UY,uy0},Evaluated->False]
] ;
(* value of Hamiltonian for given fixed point *)
f3[X_?NumberQ,Y_?NumberQ,UX_?NumberQ,UY_?NumberQ] := (H/.Thread[{x[t],y[t],ux[t],uy[t]}->{X,Y,UX,UY}]) ;
f4[t_?NumberQ] := Apply[f3,f2[t]] ;
(* find period *)
per = Q /. FindRoot[H0 - f4[Q] == 0,{Q,1}]
(* recover f.p. *)
fp = f2[per]
(* check Hamiltonian *)
(H/.Thread[{x[t],y[t],ux[t],uy[t]}->fp])
```

and the answer is:

```
1.06412 (* period *)

{10.7739, 0.0210223, 0.0700877, 37.2} (* initial condition *)
```

### Original answer

You need to solve a fixed point problem $\varphi(x) = x $
where $x$ is a vector of initial values and $\varphi$ is a solution at $t=1$.

First, define a parameter dependent system:

```
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, X, Y, UX, UY] ;
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[
 DE,
 {x[tmax],y[tmax],ux[tmax],uy[tmax]},
 {t, tmin, tmax}, 
 {X,Y,UX,UY},
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12
] ;
```

Then solve f.p. problem:

```
{xi,yi,uxi,uyi} = {X,Y,UX,UY} /. FindRoot[f[X,Y,UX,UY]=={X,Y,UX,UY},{X,x00},{Y,y0},{UX,ux0},{UY,uy0},Evaluated->False]
```

And check the answer:

```
DE = DifferentialEquations[H, om, xi, yi, uxi, uyi] ;
sol = NDSolve[DE, {x[t], y[t], ux[t], uy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", 
 PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12];
xx[t_] = x[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy[t_] = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
uxx[t_] = ux[t] /. sol[[1]];
uyy[t_] = uy[t] /. sol[[1]];
{xi,yi,uxi,uyi}
{x[t],y[t],ux[t],uy[t]} /. sol /. t -> tmax // Flatten
plot = ParametricPlot[{xx[t], yy[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, Axes -> False, 
       Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black, 
       AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Something is wrong here. Your solution reports that the periodic point is at `x00 = 10.552099826486845` which is wrong.

Comment: It is very confusing that you talk about periodic orbit while referring only to $x$. The solution given provides values for all phase space coordinates. Have you checked the value of $x$ at $t=2$ for your (FORTRAN) initial condition? Does it stay fixed?

Comment: The periodic orbit is unstable, so the orbit is no longer periodic after a couple of loops. I want to locate the `x00` position after a time interval of one period which means that the orbit has performed only one loop. Does your solution give `x00 = 774029735833850` after `t = 0.5320581245422367`?

Comment: Is the time at which you expect the orbit to overlap with its initial condition fixed by the system?  If I read correctly, I.M.'s solution looks for the case where the state at time `t=1` is equal to the initial state.  But your example completes its loop at around `t=0.53`

Comment: @JasonB No the period of the orbit is unknown.

Comment: @I.M. Your solution calculates indeed a periodic orbit but not for the desired energy level. `H00 = H /. {x[t] -> 10.589394345621207, y[t] -> 0.3293626333444296, 
   ux[t] -> 1.4893171981287268, uy[t] -> 34.247510932046005}` yields to -3144.82 but I want the periodic orbit for -3180. The value of the energy should be remain constant when you search for the `x00` value.

Comment: I believe event location would be a less computationally intensive strategy here... why not try with `WhenEvent[]`?

Comment: Reply to EDIT: The energy is conserved but the `x00` is still wrong. The initial conditions of the periodic orbit should have `y0 = ux0 = 0`, while your method gives `y0 = 0.0210214` and `ux0 = 0.0700846`. Also the routine is very slow; the fortran code gives the answer almost immediately.

Comment: Check whether your point is on the trajectory (within some tolerance, of course). Move along the suggested trajectory until you reach $x=10.77403$ and then observe the values of $y$ and $p_x$.