# Why does Mathematica's date for the battle Agincourt differ from the US Navy's?

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries

If I ask [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=battle%20of%20agincourt%20date) for the Julian Date for the battle of Agincourt with

```
WolframAlpha["battle of agincourt date"]
```

it reports `2238175`. But this does not agree with the value of `2238183.50` [reported by the US Naval Observatory](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_jdconv.pl?form=1&year=1415&month=10&day=25&era=1&hr=0&min=0&sec=0.0).

Why are these reported dates different?

Comment: Alpha is assuming a Gregorian date, when it's supposed to be a Julian one. To check, you can use my `jd[]` function from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11237): `jd[{1415, 10, 25}, "Calendar" -> "Julian"]` matches USNO's output, and `jd[{1415, 10, 25}, "Calendar" -> "Gregorian"]` is close to Alpha's.

Comment: So the USNO is using a "calendar of date" system, so to speak, while Alpha is using a proleptic Gregorian calendar?

Comment: The [docs for `JulianDate[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JulianDate.html#175196724) say as much: "All referenced dates are using the proleptic Gregorian calendar."

Comment: Another difference is that astronomical Julian days begin at noon, not midnight, which accounts for the `.5` in the USNO date.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Then the Wolfram|Alpha result is *incorrect*, right?  As "25 October 1415" is valid in the Julian calendar for this event.

Comment: @Szabolcs: [It would seem so.](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26087/were-the-dates-of-saints-days-moved-as-part-of-the-gregorian-calendar-reforms) And that would be a surprise?

Comment: For something like Wolfram|Alpha, that wants to know everything, yes, it's quite surprising ... It's exactly the kind of tool I'd expect to be able to navigate complicated calendar conversions.

Comment: @Szabolcs, they covered their bases with a caveat, as I mentioned.

Comment: @J.M. But that does't apply here because the question posted to W|A wasn't "What is the Julian day number of Oct 25, 1415".  It was, "When was the Battle of Agincourt?".  Then it gives a plainly wrong answer to that.

Comment: @rax, you could answer your own question, also.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Alpha did return the right date; unfortunately, not knowing about the "switch", it computed JD the wrong way.

Comment: @J.M.: No, it returned the wrong date: 25 October 1415 *Gregorian* (16 October Julian). That's not the date on which the battle took place.

Comment: I think we're cross-talking here. What I was trying to say was that it knew it was "October 25, 1415"; the problem was that it then interpreted that as a Gregorian date instead of a Julian one. **It knows nothing about the switch**.

Comment: @J.M.: Not really. Where it says "Result" on the Alpha panel, it states "October 25, 1415" without specifying a calendar. Later it resolves this ambiguity by giving a corresponding Julian date (of 16 October 1415). Taken together we can conclude that the date it returned as an answer is Gregorian (a reasonable default). And that date is wrong.

Comment: This bug remains unaddressed as of 2017-09-14.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The date is different because Wolfram Alpha is wrong about when the Battle of Agincourt took place.

[image]

Alpha is returning 25 October 1415 in the Gregorian calendar as the date of the battle, but the battle took place on that date in the Julian calendar (the calendar in use at the time).

That date corresponds 3 November 1415 in the proleptic Gregorian calendar used by `JulianDate`, which produces the discrepancy in Julian Dates reported by Alpha and the USNO.